# Efficient algorithm for rearranging a warehouse?

Tags: graph-theory

My problem is as follows.
I have a warehouse and a set of articles $A$. For each article $a$ I have two shelves assigned, one where it lies now $C(a)$ and one where it should lie in the future $D(a)$. One person has to move the articles. The possible locations each article $a$ at each step are the old location, the new location, and one extra shelf $S(a)$ that can serve as an intermediate storage. The functions $S, C,$ and $D$ are not necessarily injective because multiple articles can lie on a shelf.

The question now is to find an order of moving the articles that minimizes a linear combination of

1. the number of steps and
2. the total distance the person has to move.

Of course, one has to take care that when the mover moves an article to a shelf, there should be enough space on the shelf.

Have you heard of any efficient algorithm for solving this problem? Or any papers on the matter?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think that my problem reduces to Transportation Theory. I'm looking for an **order** on how to move the articles, whereas in Transportation Theory - as far as I can see from the link- you look for a **matching** between mines and factories (or, in the generalized version, a transportation map). When I posed the question I was more thinking in the direction of problems where you have to find paths satisfying certain properties...